# Laravel site down, .htaccess file keeps reappearing every time I delete it

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have a Laravel website that has been hacked in some way.

In the root directory, there now appears what looks like a Wordpress installation. I've deleted all those Wordpress files (along with my Laravel files), but there's an .htaccess file that keeps reappearing every time I delete it.

The contents of this file:

```
<FilesMatch ".(PhP|php5|suspected|phtml|py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(votes.php|index.php|wjsindex.php|lock666.php|font-editor.php|contents.php|wp-login.php|load.php|themes.php|admin.php|settings.php|bottom.php|years.php|alwso.php|service.php|license.php|module.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to edit the file and save the changes, the next second it has the old content again.

How can I solve this? Other sites I have on the same server are not affected. This particular site had `debug=true` in `.env` so that might be how the breach happened.

Comment: Wordpress has the power to regenerate an htaccess file. Why do you want it removed though? It defines what others has access to.

Comment: Sometimes you see a cached version of the FTP itself, showing you files that do not exist. Have you tried refreshing the FTP client and or connected within another client or such?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue on my laravel 7 hosted on namecheap. If your host is namecheap, you can follow the steps below.

- Zip your project and download it.
- Delete the rest of the files from the server. (note that, index.php and .htaccess won't delete but do not worry,
- Contact namecheap to help you delete the two files (.htaccess and index.php).
- Delete every instance of .htaccess on the local project you pulled down because this virus duplicated .htaccess file on every folder and sub folder of your project. On mac, you can simply run the code below

  ```
  find websitefolder -name .htaccess -delete
  ```
- The virus is been created in a folder called **css** in the root directory. It contains two files. index.html and load.php. Delete the entire folder to wipe the virus away.
- Recreate a new .htaccess. You can simply copy from another laravel project as they are always the same.
- After making sure that the public_folder of your Cpanel is empty, you can reupload your website. I'm still researching personally on the very attack that caused this issue at my own end. Maybe when I find it I can share it with you.

Comment: But how does this get rid of the underlying "virus"? Haven't you just _backed up_ the "virus" (infected files) in the first step?

Comment: The virus is been created in the root folder called css ..  It contains too files. index.html and load.php. I actually forgot to mention that So when you pull, delete the folder before you reupload too.

Comment: That would seem to be a significant point - you should add that to your answer.